# How to use ValueGeneratedOnUpdateSometimes in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

When I was configuring entities on a project, I came across `ValueGeneratedOnUpdateSometimes` on the `PropertyBuilder`. The description says

> Configures a property to have a value generated under certain conditions when saving an existing entity

However there is no solid information about how to set "certain conditions" so the value gets generated.

Is there anybody who has some information about this?

Comment: Don't worry about it. It's not in EF core 6's source code any more.

Answer (score 0):

It is used for properties mapped to the same column with entity types sharing a table.

When you change the value of one of these properties and call SaveChanges the value for the other is "generated" by propagating the value from the first one.